# Расчёт стоимости

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, функции

Есть скрипт (ниже), который должен по задумке на состояние `checkbox - checked` записывать `value` этого `checkbox`(их много) в массив, делать тоже самое с другим `checkbox` (и т.д) и выдавать на странице сумму этих значений. С этим он благо справляется. Так же с получившейся суммой необходимо провести несколько операций - отнять 20% если длинна массива 2, 30% если 3, 40 если 4 и более.
Я попытался это реализовать с помощью ещё одной функции, которая так же обращается к этому массиву. Проблема в том, что он отнимает не 20%, а больше (я пересчитывал в ручную, да и взглянув понять не сложно). Буду очень рад вашей помощи и совету.

```
/*Получаем значение по признаку checked */
var boxes = $("input:checkbox");
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function(){
  var theArray = new Array();
  for (var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++) {
   var box = boxes[i];
   if ($(box).prop('checked')) {
      theArray[theArray.length] = $(box).val();
   }
}
  showValues(theArray);
  showDiscount(theArray);
});
/* Сумма значений из массива*/
var showValues = function(array) {
  var text = "";
  if(!array.length) {
    text += "Ни одна система не выбрана";
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!text) {
     text = +array[i];
    }
    else text += +array[i];
   }
  $(".cost").html(text);
}
/* Сумма - %*/
var showDiscount = function(array) {
  var disc = "";
  var sumDisc = +array[i];
  if (!array.length) {
    disc += "Ни одна система не выбрана";
  }
  for (var i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!disc) {
     disc = +array[i];
    }
    else {
    disc += sumDisc * 0.8;
    }
  }
  $(".discount").html(disc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function calcSumWithDiscount(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + (+arr[i]);
  }

  var disc = 0;
  if (arr.length == 2)
    disc = 0.2;
  else if (arr.length == 3)
    disc = 0.3;
  else if (arr.length >= 4)
    disc = 0.4;

  sum = sum * (1 - disc);
  return sum;
}

console.log(calcSumWithDiscount([10]));
console.log(calcSumWithDiscount([10,10]));
console.log(calcSumWithDiscount([10,10,10]));
console.log(calcSumWithDiscount([10,10,10,10,10]));
```